# Books similar to "Teaching Developmentally", but for high school math

Tags: secondary-education, reference-request

I've been extremely excited by my reading of the book *Elementary and Middle School Mathematics: Teaching Developmentally* by Johan A. Van de Walle et al.

Does anyone know of similar books (or other references) for high school mathematics (grade 9-12), by which I mean either of the following:

- books that explain in detail how to set up a problem-based classroom in grade 9-12,
- books that provide a perspective of the mathematical content taught at grade 9-12 together with how teenagers best learn that content.

PS: This question is a more specific version of [A good book for Juniors/senior/high school similar to VanDeWalle middle school?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13115/a-good-book-for-juniors-senior-high-school-similar-to-vandewalle-middle-school) which has not been answered.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you're asking for, but it might come close: [What's Happening in Math Class?](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0807734810), edited by Deborah Schifter. This is volume 1, and there is a volume 2.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It looks interesting but it's not quite what I'm looking for indeed.